# Sort matrix blocks in admin by a field within the matrix?

Tags: matrix, sorting, admin

I have a Single that includes a matrix as a field. The matrix has an internal date field. Is there a way to sort the matrix blocks by the date field on the admin side to help manage the blocks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing that will automatically sort blocks for you in the Control Panel. Without writing a plugin with some very fancy JavaScript, the only way to arrange blocks is **manually**.

You can manually arrange your blocks by clicking & dragging the crosshairs in the upper-right corner of each block:

[image]